# How to play RTMPS stream with VLC

Tags: streaming, vlc, rtmp, rtmps

I have a Nimble instance that expose a RTMPS stream.
It is available at the following address on my local machine
`rtmps://127.0.0.1:8888/out/stream`

I'm trying to play this stream with VLC, specifying the same address under Media > Open Network Stream, but I'm facing the following error in VLC logs:

```
avcodec debug: CPU flags: 0x000fd3db
avcodec error: Failed to open rtmps://127.0.0.1:8888/out/stream: Unknown error 1330794744
main debug: no access modules matched
main debug: dead input
```

It seems that a module capable to open this kind of stream isn't available.

But if I turn the stream to rtmp in Nimble, it works correctly.
How can I play this kind of stream?

Comment: This may help: https://videoconverter.wondershare.com/vlc/play-rtmp-with-vlc-player.html

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but it is related to RTMP and it don't treat RTMPS, however it states that VLC 2.1 does not support RTMPE, so maybe also RTMPS could be not supported. However I'm on VLC 3.0 but knowing this I can check if this problems are still present in 3.0 version